# How to write to a <div> element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've searched around using Google and Stack Overflow, but I haven't seemed to find a answer to this. I want to write text inside a <div> element, using [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), and later clear the <div> element, and write more text into it. I am making a simple text adventure game.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
<DOCTYPE!HTML>
    <body>
        <div class="gamebox">
            <!-- I want to write in this div element -->

        </div>
    </body>
```

As a new user to JavaScript, how would I be able to write inside the `div` element gamebox? Unfortunately, my JavaScript skills are not very good, and it would be nice if you can patiently explain what happens in the code.

Comment: @mshsayem I believe he wants to write text to the div, not create a div.

Comment: @JordanFitz Yes, I want to write text inside the div. How do I accomplish that? I'm only in 8th grade, I have no professional experience with web development whatsoever, so if you would take some time to explain what happens, that'll be great. From what I can tell, document.createElement("div") creates a new html element div at document.html, correct?

Comment: Check out my answer below.

Comment: Try not to use those DOM node method to build it, use string building instead, HTML string building uses less memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` to get a reference to the first element matching any CSS selector. In your case, a class selector:

```
var div = document.querySelector(".gamebox");
```

`querySelector` works on all modern browsers, including IE8. It returns `null` if it didn't find any matching element. You can also get a list of *all* matching elements using `querySelectorAll`:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".gamebox");
```

Then you access the elements in that list using 0-based indexes (`list[0]`, `list[1]`, etc.); the length of the list is available from `list.length`.

Then you can either assign HTML strings to `innerHTML`:

```
div.innerHTML = "This is the text, <strong>markup</strong> works too.";
```

...or you can use `createElement` or `createTextNode` and `appendChild` / `insertBefore`:

```
var child = document.createTextNode("I'm text for the div");
div.appendChild(span); // Put the text node in the div
```

Those functions are found in [the DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR). A lot of them are now covered in the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) as well (particularly [Section 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom)).

Comment: From what I gather `.querySelector` / `.querySelectorAll` are especially useful for more complex selections like `".gamebox .descendantclass"` and similar selections. Looking at a http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-v-getelementsbyclassname>benchmark it seems a lot slower than `getElementsByClassName` for single class selections (93% slower it shows). Downside is IE8 and lower indeed do not seem to support `getElementsByClassName` (http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname) ;(

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers: While that's a substantial absolute performance delta, at more than three-quarters of a million queries/second, I very much doubt there's any real-world, perceptible difference. Whereas of course, QS/QSA are dramatically more useful, and supported by IE8, which is and will remain in general use for some time. :-)

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers: Of course, arguing it the other way, if one *were* worried about the performance (I can't imagine what one would be doing where it would matter, but...) and really wanted to use `getElementsByClassName`, one could do this: `if (!document.getElementsByClassName) { document.getElementsByClassName = function(cls) { return document.querySelectorAll("." + cls); }; }` (http://pastie.org/8814392) :-) Then you'd get the gain on engines that had it; IE8 is a dog anyway.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agreed, it probably does not come in to play but I found it interesting to be such a big difference. I'd guess the performance difference between the two would be very similar in case of single class selections, but it's not -- though as you pointed out for all practical cases the difference is probably negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned getElementsByClassName is faster. Important to know it when you use this you get returned an array with elements to reach the elment you want you specify its index line [0], [1]

```
var gameBox = document.getElementsByClassName('gamebox')[0];
```

Here how you can do it

```
    //returns array with elements
    var gameBox = document.getElementsByClassName('gamebox');

//inner HTML (overwrites fsd) this can be used if you direcly want to write in the div
    gameBox[0].innerHTML ='<p>the new test</p>';



//Appending when you want to add extra content

    //create new element <p>
    var newP = document.createElement('p');


    //create a new TextNode
    var newText = document.createTextNode("i'm a new text");

    //append textNode to the new element
    newP.appendChild(newText);


    //append to the DOM
    gameBox[0].appendChild(newP);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: just a little to late xD

Comment: Its ok. I'll combine this with the answer by T.J Crowder, to accomplish what I've been trying to do. :D

From what I can tell, every time I use the elm.innerhtml, it replaces the current text, right? 

For example, if I do:
elm.innerHTML = "first text"
elm.innerHTML = "second text"

I'll replace the current "first text" with "second text", right?

Comment: w3schools is a notoriously poor reference. Much better to go to primary references (such as the DOM specs I liked) or a better meta-reference, like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: Yes thats right and the sources given by T.J Crowder are better. But I just wanted to give a quick example.

Answer (score 0):

Select a single element with [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) or a collection with [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).

And then it depends, on what you want to do:

Writing [Text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) into the div or [create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) an Element and [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) it to the div.